# Can I remove "be" from "had ordered to be shut the big river gates"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> Down in the valley there was a roar and a hiss. Someone more thoughtful than the rest had ordered **to be shut** the big river gates that were at the point where the Ankh flowed out of the twin city

rephrased as

> Down in the valley there was a roar and a hiss. Someone more thoughtful than the rest had ordered **to  shut** the big river gates that were at the point where the Ankh flowed out of the twin city.

Comment: I think "someone ... had ordered shut the big river gates" would be another alternative. You can order the gates to shut themselves (which would make more sense if the gates had an associated workforce), you can order someone to shut the gates (either specifying who should do it or making a general call), or you can state that the gates should be in a shut state without explicitly commanding anyone to shut them (the difference between "He should be at home right now", "He should go home", and "Take him home!").

Answer (score 0):

This is a very hard sentence to phrase in a way that is both grammatical and easy to understand. The fundamental problem is that no agents are being identified. The best that I can come up with is

> Someone thoughtful ordered the big gates to be shut where the river Ankh flowed from the twin city

Alternatively

> Someone thoughtful ordered shutting the big gates where the river Ankh flowed from the twin city.

Of course, if what is meant is that someone complied with the order, neither of those fully captures the intended meaning.

> At the order of someone thoughtful, the big gates where the river Ankh flowed from the twin city were shut.

EDIT: To clarify what I meant about identifying agents consider

> X obeyed Y's thoughtful order to shut the big gates where the river Ankh flowed from the twin city

Even if you replace X or Y with "somone" we learn that there was obedience to a thoughtful order to shut the gates.

Answer (score -4):

Yes- The second usage is correct. In the first sentence "**to be shut**" is the wrong usage because we have to specify first what we "ordered to be shut", in this case, its the river gates. So you could write **Someone more thoughtful than the rest had ordered the river gates to be shut**. I Think this is the correct usage in that sentence.

Comment: I doubt that the construction **had ordered to shut the big....** can be considered correct.without the insertion of some agent (**them, the workers**) before the infinitive.

Comment: @RonaldSole I agree. "Order" is a transitive verb, and omission of an explicit object calls for a passive construction.